# Auto split text the numbers

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to past the IP in `1 textbox` and when I press OK is must split in 4 pieces like:

> 123.123.123.123

and split in `textbox1`,2,3,4 like `[123] [123] [123] [123]` all is ok but if i put more numbers 123.123.123.123.123.123.123 I get errors.

```
    Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim splitStr As String() = str.Split(".")
    TextBox1.Text = splitStr(0).ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = splitStr(1).ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = splitStr(2).ToString()
    TextBox4.Text = splitStr(3).ToString()
```

Comment: Are you saying that you currently encounter errors in that situation, or that you want to know how to display an error to the user if they enter a bad value like that?

Comment: so what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This covers most input errors:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""

    Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
    str = str.Trim
    Dim splitStrs As String() = str.Split("."c)

    If splitStrs.Length <> 4 Then
        MsgBox("Not a valid IP format")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each value As String In splitStrs
        If value.Length < 1 OrElse value.Length > 3 Then
            MsgBox("Not a valid IP format")
            Exit Sub
        End If


        If Not Integer.TryParse(value, 0) Then
            MsgBox("Not a valid IP format")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If value.Contains(" ") Then
            MsgBox("Not a valid IP format")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = splitStrs(0).ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = splitStrs(1).ToString()
    TextBox3.Text = splitStrs(2).ToString()
    TextBox4.Text = splitStrs(3).ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the length of the string to 15 Characters

4 x 3 characters "000"
plus
 3 x separators "."

Total 15 characters

Comment: then I'll type "1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1" into the box :)

Comment: :) yep is is bug like that